# How to do CRUD operations with Back4App?

Tags: android, android-studio, crud, back4app

Hello I am developing a Café App for the thesis project and I am using Back4App as my backend.

I was wondering if it is possible to Add, Edit, Delete café items within the app from the Back4App backend website?

I was hoping it can be done within the website and not to create an admin side on the Café app itself. Any help is welcome!

Comment: You can either use the Parse Dashboard that we have available for managing the database, or the admin app that back4app automatically generates (you can find it under More menu)

Comment: Thank You Davi for the tips. I will definitely check it out